# Composer require showing error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I have my application running using laravel 5.7 and when I install any package it throws some error . I searched the error in the google but I did not get any post which could help me.

This is the package I am trying to install :

```
sudo composer require mpdf/mpdf
```

The php-parse file is available in the path provided. Please help me if anybody has the solution for this

Please check the attachment of the error I get

[image]

[image]

Comment: for future reference Its better to copy/paste text from the terminal that show us pictures

Comment: Also, please share your attempts to resolve the given error message

Answer (score 3):

There are some things that can go wrong. First the folder `vendor/bin` isn't created because of some missing permission. So check all you permission on that folder.The next thing create folder to test if it's working.

So the main problem is that directory doesn't exist or can't be created.Create it on your own and run your command again.